# How to handle item selection from a list that behaves like a combobox in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I'm working on a very simple LWC, does anyone know how to get the selected item from a list? The idea is that when the user clicks on a country, the dropdown closes and shows not the "Select your country" message but the selected country. I used a button that behaves like a combobox so I could use images in each option.

Here is the html and the js method. I've tried many things, the one I'm current at made sense but still not working, the console shows me "undefined".

Can you please share some guidance? I'm painfully new to javascript

```
<template>
        <div class="drop">
            <button id="btndrop" class="btn">Select your country</button>
            <div class="drop-content">
                <ul id="countryList">
                    <li class="country" value="Argentina" onclick={handleclick}>
                            <img src={flag1}/>Argentina</li>
                    <li class="country" value="Brasil" onclick={handleclick}> 
                            <img src={flag2} /> Brasil</li>
                    <li class="country" value="Colombia" onclick={handleclick}>
                            <img src={flag3} /> Colombia</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
        <button id="ShowButton" class="button slds-max-medium-align_absolute-center">Next</button>
  </div>
    
</template>
```

This is the js function

```
    handleclick() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("country").value;
        console.log(x);
        document.getElementById("btndrop").innerText = x;                          
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code i see.

1. LWC does not support `getElementById`. lwc class properties are reactive meaning when you update their value the DOM will re-render and shows updated values.
2. `value` is not a supported attribute on `li`.

I've made few changes. You can also see it [live on playground](https://app.lwc.studio/view/rlirZRwEaznTkjsDuAKR/src/app.js?p=stories).

html

```
<template>
    <div class="drop app">
        <button id="btndrop" class="btn" onclick={handleCountriesSelection}>{country}</button>
        <div class="drop-content" if:true={showCountries}>
            <ul id="countryList">
                <li class="country" data-value="Argentina" onclick={handleclick}>
                    <img src={flag1}/>Flag 1
                </li>
                <li class="country" data-value="Brasil" onclick={handleclick}>
                    <img src={flag2} /> Flag 2
                </li>
                <li class="country" data-value="Colombia" onclick={handleclick}>
                    <img src={flag3} /> Flag 3
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
        <button id="ShowButton" class="button slds-max-medium-align_absolute-center">Next</button>
    </div>

</template>
```

js

```
  country = 'Select your Country';
  showCountries = false;
  flag1 = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/197/197374.png";
  flag2 = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/206/206626.png";
  flag3 = "https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/197/197571.png";

  handleCountriesSelection(){
    this.toggleCountriesList();
  }

  handleclick(event){
    const { value } = event.currentTarget.dataset;
    this.country = value;
    this.toggleCountriesList();
  }

  toggleCountriesList(){
    this.showCountries = !this.showCountries;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, it's kinda frustrating the little knowledge I have of javascript, it's of no use with lwc. The toggle works, although when a country is selected, the flag disappears